# how to remove links from a html content using php

Tags: php, html, preg-replace

I have the following html content:

```
<p>My name is <a href="way2project">way2project</a></p>
```

Now I want this text as `<p>My name is way2project</p>`

Is there any way to do this? Please help me thanks

I used preg_replace but in vain.

Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want your hyperlink to appear like normal text? Please make your question more clear.

Comment: So `$blurb = preg_replace('/<[^>]*>/', '', $blurb);` doesnt work?

Comment: You may want to read into: [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). Regex is (most of the time) not suited to parse HTML.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an HTML element using the DOMDocument class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171597/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-the-domdocument-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) you can use this, to remove html tags.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function

```
$string = '<p>My name is <a href="way2project">way2project</a></p>';

echo strip_tags($string,'<p>');
```

note the second parameter is the list of allowed tags you wont to ignore.

Comment: also, strip_tags will strip ALL HTML tags. Sounds like he only wants to remove anchor tags

Comment: @jackwanders yes it does, but you can use the second parameter to take care of that.

Comment: the second parameter lets you list allowable tags. it would work for this specific example, yes. But to reliably use this with arbitrary chunks of HTML, he'd have to list ALL html tags except for <a> in that second parameter

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Simple Html Dom Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

```
$html = str_get_html('<html><body>Hello!<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">SO</a></body></html>');
echo $html->find('a',0)->innertext; //prints "SO"
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems strange, but not knowing the complete scope of your issue and seeing that you want to do this in PHP, you can try:

```
$origstring = '<p>My name is <a href="way2project">way2project</a></p>';
$newstring = str_replace('<a href="way2project">way2project</a>', 'way2project', $origstring);

echo $newstring;
```