# PHP DOMDocument : How remove a div?

Tags: php, domdocument, removechild

Here is my code :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(stripslashes($sContent));

// si le meta existe alors il y a un sondage
if($doc->getElementById('meta') != null){
    $nombreMeta = $doc->getElementById('meta')->nodeValue;
    $numSondage = $doc->getElementById('meta')->getAttribute('class');
    for($i=0;$i<$nombreMeta;$i++){
        $meta = $meta."0,";
    }
    $meta = substr($meta,0,-1); 
    $divMeta = $doc->getElementById('meta');
    $oldchapter = $doc->removeChild($divMeta);
    $oHead = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')->item(0);
    $oMeta2 = $doc->createElement('meta');
    $oMeta2->setAttribute('name',"metapoll".$numSondage);
    $oMeta2->setAttribute('content',$meta);
    $oHead->insertBefore($oMeta2, $oHead->firstChild);
    $sContent = $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

I'm trying to remove div with `id="meta"` `($doc->getElementById('meta'))`, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

I have tested lots of things like :

```
$metmet = $doc->documentElement;
$divMeta = $metmet->getElementById('meta')->item(0);
$metmet->removeChild($divMeta);
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: You should post your HTML code as well. My first guess is you don't have any tag with an ID of "meta", but you rather have "meta" tags in your <head>. Am I right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an HTML element using the DOMDocument class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171597/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-the-domdocument-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `removeChild` method removes a child element from a node. A div cannot be a child element of the `document` object, only `<html>` can be (in an HTML document).

Having found the div you want to remove, you need to fetch its parent node. Then call `removeChild` on that.

```
$divMeta->parentNode->removeChild($divMeta)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work:

```
$divMeta = $doc->getElementById('meta');
$divMeta->parentNode->removeChild($divMeta);
```

- [`removeChild`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php)
- [`parentNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.parentnode)