# How to get full HTML from DOMXPath::query() method?

Tags: php, domdocument

I have document from which I want to extract specific div with it's untouched content.
I do:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);//that's HTML of my document, string
```

and xpath query:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath_resultset =  $xpath->query("//div[@class='text']");
/*I'm after div class="text"*/
```

now I do `item(0)` method on what I get with `$xpath_resultset`

```
$my_content = $xpath_resultset->item(0);
```

what I get is object (not string) $my_content which I can echo or settype() to string, but as result I get is with fully stripped markup?

What to do to get **all** from div class='text' here?

Comment: Have you tried the `saveXML` / `saveHTML` methods?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::saveHTML() in C:\wamp\www\3\test.php on line 17. I did...

Comment: Then either upgrade PHP or use `saveXML` instead.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just pass the node to the [`DOMDocument::saveHTML`](http://php.net/manual/domdocument.savehtml.php) method:

```
$htmlString = $dom->saveHTML($xpath_resultset->item(0));
```

This will give you a string representation of that particular DOMNode and all its children.

Comment: That method requires PHP 5.3.6, an alternative is to use DOMDocument::saveXML which only requires PHP 5.