# CURL/PHP - Trying to parse link giving Call to undefined method DOMDocument::query()

Tags: php, curl

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-goletto-mens-astro-turf-trainers-263244?colcode=26324408";   

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);  


    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile($str);

    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $name  = $doc->query('//span[@id="ProductName"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

    echo $name;

?>
```

I am trying to get the name of the product but i receive:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::query() in /public_html/test.php on line 24
```

Can you please help me out resolve my problem and find my mistake because i am stuck on this problem for hours?

I just want to get the name of the product which is contained in `span` element with `id` ProductName.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you call it on `$xpath` and not on `$doc`?

Comment: I am not sure, can you please make an answer with your suggestion ?

Comment: Just replace `$doc` with `$xpath` in this line: `$name  = $doc->query('//span[@id="ProductName"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: With this i get just a blank screen. No errors but not parsing is done either. So i think this just not resolve my problem.

Comment: This page is not valid `xml`, it's just `html`. So your `$doc` is empty xml

Comment: Have you tried googling the error?! 99% of the time you'll get the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full HTML from DOMXPath::query() method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012395/how-to-get-full-html-from-domxpathquery-method)

Answer (score -1):

You can get the desired result by using PHP regexes:

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/adidas-goletto-mens-astro-turf-trainers-263244?colcode=26324408";   

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$str = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);

preg_match_all("/id=\"ProductName\"(.+?)>(.+?)</", $str, $str_out);

$name = $str_out[2][0];

echo $name;
?>
```

This works using preg_match_all() to extract the product name.